# How to make script to replace double space to tab?

Tags: python, scripting, str-replace

i need help to make a script contain two process by python:
find each text in new folder and replace all double space to 1 tab and do it again to replace every double tab to 1 tab.

```
import fnmatch 
import os 
rootPath = "D:\A\B" 
pattern = '*.txt' 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:\A\B"): 
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): 
        print(os.path.join(filename))
```

Comment: do you mean tab?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't put code in a comment -- edit you're question in future. I've done it for you this time :)

Comment: im still beginner

Comment: You can use `tabnanny`, just iterate over all files and call tabnanny with the required parameters: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tabnanny.html

Comment: Thank you so useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) package is probably a bit more concise that what you're using. Then just open up the files, read the text in, replace what you want to replace and write it back to the same file.

Be careful when editing files in place -- if you use this in the wrong place you could cause some serious damage.

```
import os
import glob

root_path = r'D:\a\b'  # use raw strings so \ is not escape character
patten = r'**\*.txt'

for path in glob.iglob(os.path.join(root_path, pattern), recursive=True):

    # open the file to read and replace
    with open(path) as fr:
        text = fr.read().replace('  ', '\t').replace('\t\t', '\t')

    # open the file to overwrite
    with open(path, 'w') as fw:
        path.write(text)
```

Comment: Really Thank you but i tried it and my files had no changed , kindly advice!